# how install ubuntu desktop on tablet genesis gt 8220s (replace the android tablet system)

Tags: 16.04, 15.04, android, tablet

Hiii peoples, I need a very important help on Linux and android. I am very lazy in the area but would like to install linux desktop on my tablet genesis GT 8220s. I do not want emulator and yes linux desktop knows. So.. Do you know or could you send me some tutorial or installation steps? (I want to replace the android tablet system in linux desktop)

If anyone can help, right now you have my acknowledgment!

my email: 21mgodi@gmail.com

Thank you very much for your attention friend! :)